# Scalable server for MMO

Tags: mmo, server

We are looking for the solution for game server for instantiating game instance on nodes.

We tried to use [this](http://developer.muchdifferent.com/unitypark/uZone2/uZone2) solution, but it has scalable problems, as you can see on diagram:
[image]

Cause only 1 instance of Zone Master can be instantiate in same time and it doesn't support replication. So if it shuts down, players cant' play anymore.

So we are trying to find better scalable solution. Any suggestion?

P.S. game has more than 10k users online

Comment: Scalability of big servers like this is a very broad topic. There's no single correct answer to a problem like this. If you have a strategy in mind and have a specific question regarding that strategy, you should ask that instead.

Comment: I really don't think it's a too broad question. He has a specific question.

Comment: He has a *specific question* but that question is asking for a technology that is "better" (subjective) than his current solution. It thus a list-generator, which is considered too broad (it's also a which-technology question, which is also off-topic).

Comment: I don't want, actually, better solution. I just want solution with replication/good fault tolerance. Don't think that there to much solutions for this.